# Как передать объект Activity в конструктор?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Есть MainActivity, где запускается FragmentAdd:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    new FragmentControl(this).addFragment(new FragmentAdd());
}}
```

Класс FragmentControl, для взаимодействия с фрагментами:

```
class FragmentControl{
private AppCompatActivity activity;

FragmentControl(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

private FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    return fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
}

void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getFragmentTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}

void removeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getFragmentTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}

void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getFragmentTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}}
```

Выгладит FragmentAdd след. образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

FragmentAdd:

```
public class FragmentAdd extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
    Button buttonAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             /*Неправильно!!!!*/
            new FragmentControl(new MainActivity()).replaceFragment(new FragmentCreate());
        }
    });
    return view;
}}
```

Здесь по нажатию должен появиться второй фрагмент FragmentCreate, но как мне передать ему activity? Если передам как new MainActivity, то возникает ошибка, что она уничтожена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте активити, в которой находится ваш фрагмент:

```
new FragmentControl(getActivity()).replaceFragment(new FragmentCreate());
```

А ещё лучше - не создавайте новый FragmentControl, а используйте уже имеющийся как-то так:

в активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentControl fragmentControl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        fragmentControl = new FragmentControl(this);
        fragmentControl.addFragment(new FragmentAdd());
    }}

    public FragmentControl getFragmentControl() {
        return fragmentControl;
    }
}
```

во фрагменте:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getFragmentControl().replaceFragment(new FragmentCreate());
```

---

А вообще, вы, кажется, изобретаете `Router` типа вот этой либы: https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone

Comment: После того как я запущу второй фрагмент, я смогу кнопкой назад перейти к прошлому фрагменту?

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, да, если добавите его в `backStack` - сделайте это в транзакции

Comment: Чтобы возвратиться назад, мне нужно добавить в стек второй или первый фрагмент?

Comment: Разобрался, благодарю за помощь=)

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, если один из ответов решил вашу проблему, вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку, слева от тела ответа)